# Google Colab not updating package?

Tags: python, seaborn, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use seaborn==0.8.1 in an ipynb on Google colab. Here is my code:

```
"""General import statements and settings config."""
!pip install seaborn==0.8.1
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
pd.set_option('max_columns', 10)
color = sns.color_palette()[0]
print (sns.__version__)
```

However, this outputs the following:

```
Requirement already satisfied: seaborn==0.8.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (0.8.1)
0.7.1
```

If the requirement is satisfied why am I importing the old version of Seaborn?

Comment: use pip install --upgrade packageName

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue here is that Colab imports seaborn at startup, before you've `pip install`'d the new version. If you restart your runtime after the install, you'll pick up the new version.

Answer (score 6):

`!pip install seaborn --upgrade packageName` and then restart the kernel/runtime.

If you just need to upgrade seaborn in a hosted collab notebook to the latest version then run 
`!pip install seaborn --upgrade` and then restart the kernel/runtime.