# How to create a dictionary such that output contains the list and the paragraph values in a dictionary

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup, data-extraction

it will be great help if i will be able to know how to resolve the issues to get the proper output in json file

```
r = requests.get('https://www.iomfsa.im/enforcement/disqualified-directors/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
paragraphs=[]
length=soup.findAll("strong") 
for leng in length: 
    paragraphs.append(leng.next_sibling)
paragraph = [i for i in paragraphs if i is not None]
print(paragraph)
list=['name','address','DOB','POD','DOD','Particulars of Disqualification Order or Undertaking']
```

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYGqY.png)

Comment: First off, don't name variables for [built-ins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) like `list` - it shadows them and leads to issues down the road. Second, [*please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool (`{}` button) to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments, and cannot be copied for testing and debugging purposes. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: surely will imply this in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
import re
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

headers= {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

url = 'https://www.iomfsa.im/enforcement/disqualified-directors/'

df_list = []
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'xml')
# print(soup)
dismissed_dirs = soup.select('section.accordion-item')
for d in dismissed_dirs:
#     print(d)
    name = d.find('strong', text=re.compile('^Name:')).next_sibling
    address = d.find('strong', text=re.compile('^Address')).next_sibling
    dob = d.find('strong', text=re.compile('^Date of Birth:')).next_sibling
    pod = d.find('strong', text=re.compile('^Period of Disqualification:')).next_sibling
    dod = d.find('strong', text=re.compile('^Dates of Disqualification:')).parent.text
    particulars = d.find('strong', text=re.compile('^Particulars')).find_next('a').text
    df_list.append((name, address, dob, pod, dod, particulars))

df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns = ['name', 'address', 'dob', 'pod', 'dod', 'particulars'])
    
print(df)
print('--------------')
print(df.to_dict(orient='records'))
```

This will return both a dataframe (which makes more sense, visually), as well as a dictionary, as you requested:

|  | name | address | dob | pod | dod | particulars |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John Trevor Roche Baines | c/o Isle of Man Prison, Jurby, Isle of Man | 19 Dec 1939 | 15 Years 0 Months 0 Days | Dates of Disqualification: From 15 Jul 2010 To 15 Jul 2025 | Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009 |
| 1 | Ralph Stephen Brunswick | Valdfrieden, Ballaugh Glen, Ballaugh, Isle of Man IM7 5JB |  | 13 Years 6 Months 0 Days | Dates of Disqualification: From 4 Mar 2009 To 4 Sep 2022 | Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009 |
| 2 | Fenella Jane Carter | 30 North Quay, Douglas, Isle of Man IM1 4LD | 6 August 1984 | 6 Years 0 Months 0 Days | Dates of Disqualification: From 5 July 2018 to 5 July 2024 | Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009 |
| 3 | Richard Alan Costain | St Patrick's Close, Jurby, Isle of Man | 13 Sep 1951 | 15 Years 0 Months 0 Days | Dates of Disqualification: From 16 Feb 2017 To 16 Feb 2032 | Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009 |
| 4 | Paul Deighton | Isle of Man Prison, St Patrick’s Close, Coast Road IM7 3JP | 23 December 1966 | 12 Years 0 Months 0 Days | Dates of Disqualification: From 8 August 2020 to 7 August 2032 | Section 4 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009 |
| 5 | Jamie Alexander Irving | Meadowcourt, The Links, Douglas Road, Peel, Isle of Man, IM5 1LN | Not known | 7 Years 0 Months 0 Days | Dates of Disqualification: From 26 Feb 2018 To 26 Feb 2025 | Section 4 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009 |
| 6 | Jonathan Frank Edward Irving | Meadowcourt, The Links, Douglas Road, Peel, Isle of Man, IM5 1LN | Not known | 8 Years 0 Months 0 Days | Dates of Disqualification: From 26 Feb 2018 To 26 Feb 2026 | Section 4 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009 |
| 7 | Duncan Frank Ellis Jones | Harpers Glen, Hillberry Green, Douglas, Isle of Man IM2 6DE | 10 Aug 1959 | 13 Years 0 Months 0 Days | Dates of Disqualification: From 25 Apr 2011 To 25 Apr 2024 | Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009 |
| 8 | Lynn Keig | Croit-e-Quill, Lonan, Isle of Man, IM4 7JG | 28 June 1956 | Years 0 Months 0 Days | Dates of Disqualification: From 29 Jun 2017 To 28 Jun 2023 | Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009 |
| 9 | Richard Ian Kissack | 6 Falcon Cliff Court, Douglas, Isle of Man, IM2 4AQ (currently Mr Kissack is residing at HM IOM Prison, Jurby, Isle of Man) | **30 October 1968** | 5 Years 11 Months 13 Days | Dates of Disqualification: From 31 December 2021 to 13 December 2027 | Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009 |
| 10 | Alan Louis | Not known | 23 November 1965 | 12 Years 0 Months 0 Days | Dates of Disqualification: From 29 April 2019 to 28 April 2031 | Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009 |
| 11 | Phillip Sean McCarthy | Cedar Lodge, Main Road, Crosby IM4 4BH | 5 October 1979 | 8 Years 0 Months 0 Days | Dates of Disqualification: From 28 November 2019 to 27 November 2027 | Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009 |
| 12 | John McCauley | Not known | 30 March 1955 | 5 Years 0 Months 0 Days | Dates of Disqualification: From 29 April 2019 to 28 April 2024 | Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009 |
| 13 | Dirk Frederik Mudge | 92, Daan Bekker Street, Windhoek, Namibia | 23 December 1976 | 8 Years 0 Months 0 Days | Dates of Disqualification: From 17 November 2018 to 16 November 2026 | Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009 |
| 14 | Lukas Nakos | Not known | 6 March 1976 | 6 Years 0 Months 0 Days | Dates of Disqualification: From 29 April 2019 to 28 April 2025 | Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009 |
| 15 | Andrew Mark Rouse | 13 Reayrt Ny Chrink, Crosby, Isle of Man IM4 2EA | 24 Jan 1977 | 5 Years 0 Months 0 Days | Dates of Disqualification: From 28 Feb 2018 To 28 Feb 2023 | Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009 |

```
--------------
[{'name': 'John Trevor Roche Baines', 'address': 'c/o Isle of Man Prison, Jurby, Isle of Man', 'dob': '19 Dec 1939', 'pod': '15 Years 0 Months 0 Days', 'dod': 'Dates of Disqualification: From 15 Jul 2010 To 15 Jul 2025', 'particulars': 'Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009'}, {'name': 'Ralph Stephen Brunswick', 'address': 'Valdfrieden, Ballaugh Glen, Ballaugh, Isle of Man IM7 5JB', 'dob': None, 'pod': '13 Years 6 Months 0 Days', 'dod': 'Dates of Disqualification: From 4 Mar 2009 To 4 Sep 2022', 'particulars': 'Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009'}, {'name': ' Fenella Jane Carter', 'address': '30 North Quay, Douglas, Isle of Man IM1 4LD', 'dob': '6 August 1984', 'pod': '6 Years 0 Months 0 Days', 'dod': 'Dates of Disqualification: From\xa05 July 2018 to 5 July 2024', 'particulars': 'Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009'}, {'name': 'Richard Alan Costain', 'address': "St Patrick's Close, Jurby, Isle of Man", 'dob': '13 Sep 1951', 'pod': '15 Years 0 Months 0 Days', 'dod': 'Dates of Disqualification: From 16 Feb 2017 To 16 Feb 2032', 'particulars': 'Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009'}, {'name': ' Paul Deighton', 'address': 'Isle of Man Prison, St Patrick’s Close, Coast Road IM7 3JP', 'dob': '23 December 1966', 'pod': '12 Years 0 Months 0 Days', 'dod': 'Dates of Disqualification: From\xa08 August 2020 to 7 August 2032', 'particulars': 'Section\xa04 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009'}, {'name': 'Jamie Alexander Irving', 'address': 'Meadowcourt, The Links, Douglas Road, Peel, Isle of Man, IM5 1LN', 'dob': 'Not known', 'pod': '7 Years 0 Months 0 Days', 'dod': 'Dates of Disqualification: From\xa026 Feb 2018 To\xa026 Feb 2025', 'particulars': 'Section\xa04 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009'}, {'name': 'Jonathan Frank Edward Irving', 'address': 'Meadowcourt, The Links, Douglas Road, Peel, Isle of Man, IM5 1LN', 'dob': 'Not known', 'pod': '8 Years 0 Months 0 Days', 'dod': 'Dates of Disqualification: From\xa026 Feb 2018 To\xa026 Feb 2026', 'particulars': 'Section\xa04 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009'}, {'name': 'Duncan Frank Ellis Jones', 'address': 'Harpers Glen, Hillberry Green, Douglas, Isle of Man IM2 6DE', 'dob': '10 Aug 1959', 'pod': '13 Years 0 Months 0 Days', 'dod': 'Dates of Disqualification: From 25 Apr 2011 To 25 Apr 2024', 'particulars': 'Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009'}, {'name': 'Lynn Keig', 'address': 'Croit-e-Quill, Lonan, Isle of Man, IM4 7JG', 'dob': '28 June 1956', 'pod': ' Years 0 Months 0 Days', 'dod': 'Dates of Disqualification: From\xa029 Jun 2017 To 28 Jun 2023', 'particulars': 'Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009'}, {'name': ' Richard Ian Kissack', 'address': '6 Falcon Cliff Court, Douglas, Isle of Man, IM2 4AQ (currently Mr Kissack is residing at HM IOM Prison, Jurby, Isle of Man)', 'dob': <strong>30 October 1968</strong>, 'pod': '5 Years 11 Months 13 Days', 'dod': 'Dates of Disqualification: From\xa031 December 2021 to 13 December 2027', 'particulars': 'Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009'}, {'name': ' Alan Louis', 'address': 'Not known', 'dob': '23 November 1965', 'pod': '12 Years 0 Months 0 Days', 'dod': 'Dates of Disqualification: From\xa029 April 2019 to 28 April 2031', 'particulars': 'Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009'}, {'name': ' Phillip Sean McCarthy', 'address': 'Cedar Lodge, Main Road, Crosby IM4 4BH', 'dob': '5 October 1979', 'pod': '8 Years 0 Months 0 Days', 'dod': 'Dates of Disqualification: From\xa028 November 2019 to 27 November 2027', 'particulars': 'Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009'}, {'name': ' John McCauley', 'address': 'Not known', 'dob': '30 March 1955', 'pod': '5 Years 0 Months 0 Days', 'dod': 'Dates of Disqualification: From\xa029 April 2019 to 28 April 2024', 'particulars': 'Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009'}, {'name': ' Dirk Frederik Mudge', 'address': '92, Daan Bekker Street, Windhoek, Namibia', 'dob': '23 December 1976', 'pod': '8 Years 0 Months 0 Days', 'dod': 'Dates of Disqualification: From\xa017 November 2018 to\xa016 November 2026', 'particulars': 'Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009'}, {'name': ' Lukas Nakos', 'address': 'Not known', 'dob': '6 March 1976', 'pod': '6 Years 0 Months 0 Days', 'dod': 'Dates of Disqualification: From\xa029 April 2019 to 28 April 2025', 'particulars': 'Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009'}, {'name': 'Andrew Mark Rouse', 'address': '13 Reayrt Ny Chrink, Crosby, Isle of Man IM4 2EA', 'dob': '24 Jan 1977', 'pod': '5 Years 0 Months 0 Days', 'dod': 'Dates of Disqualification: From\xa028 Feb 2018 To\xa028 Feb 2023', 'particulars': 'Section 2 Company Officers (Disqualification) Act 2009'}]
```

Comment: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [name, address, dob, pod, dod, particulars]
Index: []
--------------
[]

Comment: @JAGRITIPRIYADARSHANI update your packages, and use the exact code I wrote above. It will work, I tested it before posting.

Comment: Do a pip freeze @JAGRITIPRIYADARSHANI What version is your bs4 package? And requests, and pandas?

Comment: @platipus-on_fire the versions are #bs4==0.0.1
#pandas==1.3.5
#requests==2.23.0 in google colab

Comment: Upgrade them. Do `pip install -U bs4`, `pip install -U pandas` and  `pip install -U requests`. After that, beautifulsoup4 should be 4.11.1, requests should be 2.28.1, and pandas should be 1.4.3.

Comment: So you upgraded the packages? As I instructed above? what is your beautifulsoup package version now? The code is fine.

Comment: @platipus-on_fire i guess some issue while extracting particulars.................particulars = d.find('strong', text=re.compile('^Particulars')).find_next('a').text
 print(name+" "+address+" "+dob)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next'

Comment: THis starts to be tiring for me. Again, what is your beautifulsoup version now, after upgrading? And did you run the code exactly as posted above?

Comment: what is your beautifulsoup package version? after upgrading them, restart the kernel and check again. It should pick up the new versions.

Comment: beautifulsoup4==4.6.3

Comment: It should be beautifulsoup4==4.11.1. THe following question shows how to upgrade your packages on google colab: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51226306/google-colab-not-updating-package Try to follow those instructions, upgrade beautifulsoup (with `!pip install bs4 --upgrade`), then restart the kernel (or that runtime, whatever google is calling it). It should work. Code is tested and working. Also, do not forget to upgrade pip (`!pip install --upgrade pip`) before upgrading packages.